# Hover div overlap, part don't hover now: z-index doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have this code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbQQWo
(In fact I have more rows and divs, but this is enough to understand)

```
 <div class= "row">
          <div class ="rhombus" id = "r1c"></div>
          <div class ="rhombus" id = "r2c"></div>
 </div>
 <div class= "row2">
          <div class ="rhombus" id = "r3c"></div>
 </div>

.rhombus {
  width: 32vw;
    height: 32vw;
  margin: -3.5vw 6.8vw;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transform: scaleY(.575) rotate(45deg) ;
  float:left;
}

.row
{
 position: absolute;

   margin-top: 0vw;

}

.row2
{
  margin-left: 22.8vw;
 margin-top: 13.2vw;
   position: absolute;
}

.rhombus:hover
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

As you can see in the demo, the bottom left side doesn't work (rc2) and the bottom right side (rc1) (because the row overlap that part). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `pointer-events` to your css rules your `rhombus` will get the `hover` effect.

```css
.row2, .row {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.rhombus {
  width: 32vw;
  height: 32vw;
  margin: -3.5vw 6.8vw;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transform: scaleY(.575) rotate(45deg) ;
  float:left;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.row2 {
  margin-left: 22.8vw;
  margin-top: 13.2vw;
  position: absolute;
}

.rhombus:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class= "row">
  <div class ="rhombus" id = "r1c"></div>
  <div class ="rhombus" id = "r2c"></div>
</div>
<div class= "row2">
  <div class ="rhombus" id = "r3c"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you a lot!